# Как узнать, что страница прокручена до самого низа, чтобы выполнить AJAX запрос?

Tags: javascript, ajax, прокрутка

Как узнать, что страница прокручена до самого низа, чтобы выполнить AJAX запрос? Не могу понять логику. Код пишу на чистом JS без использования jQuery. Буду благодарен если разъясните.

> По загрузке клиентской страницы выведите имена работников в в виде
> списка ul. При этом обведите теги li границей и задайте им высоту в
> 200-300 пикселей так, чтобы появилась вертикальная полоса прокрутки.
> Сделайте так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы до самого низа из базы
> подгружалось еще 3 записи, пока они не будут загружены все.

Comment: Тут есть ответ, правда на английском. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom/3898152

Comment: И к сожалению с использованием jQuery которого я не знаю. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver), там есть примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
   if(pageYOffset + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.scrollHeight){
      // code
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут еще один вариант решения с картинками для наглядного восприятия.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight